# Evaluating problematic function when cdf is close to one?

Tags: r, distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, numerical-integration

Let $F(x;\theta)$ be a cumulative distribution function and $\beta>0$. I need to evaluate

$$\rho=\frac{F(x;\theta)^\beta}{F(x;\theta)-F(x;\theta)^{\beta+1}},$$

but for some values of $\theta$, `R` returns $F(x;\theta)=1$, and then I have some problems calculating $\rho$. The CDF is not exactly 1 at those parameter values. Is there a trick to obtain a stable calculation of $\rho$?

Comment: For most built-in functions, `R` supports options to (a) return the *complementary* CDF and/or (b) return its *logarithm.*  Can you avail yourself of them?  if not, then apply L'Hopital's Rule to estimate $\rho.$

Comment: @whuber so, are you suggesting to calculate $F = 1 - (1-F)$?

Comment: Sort of--but there will be algebraic cancellation.  If you let $z=1-F,$ then to second order in $z,$ $$\rho = \frac{1}{\beta}z^{-1} + \frac{\beta-1}{2\beta} + \frac{\beta^2-1}{12\beta}z + O(z^2).$$ Thus, depending on the size of $\beta$ (you need  $1/\beta$ and $z/\beta$ to be small), all you really need is a decent estimate of $z.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $W_x(\theta) \equiv \log F(x|\theta)$ and note that $W_x(\theta) \leqslant 0$ since it is a log-probability.  (Since you have specified that $F(x|\theta)$ is close to one, this means that $W_x(\theta)$ is close to zero.)  Then you can have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\log \rho 
&= \beta \log F(x;\theta) - \log ( F(x;\theta)-F(x;\theta)^{\beta+1}) \\[6pt]
&= (\beta-1) \log F(x;\theta) - \log ( 1 - F(x;\theta)^\beta) \\[6pt]
&= (\beta-1) \log F(x;\theta) - \log ( 1 - \exp(\beta \log F(x;\theta))) \\[6pt]
&= (\beta-1) W_x(\theta) - \log ( 1 - \exp(\beta W_x(\theta))) \\[6pt]
&= (\beta-1) W_x(\theta) - \text{log1mexp}(-\beta W_x(\theta)), \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where $\text{log1mexp}(a) \equiv \log (1-e^{-a})$.  Accurate calculation of expression hinges on accurate calculation of the $\text{log1mexp}$ function for argument values $a$ near zero.  Accurate calculation of this function is considered in [Machler (2012)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/log1mexp-note.pdf), and is implemented in the `VGAM` package in `R`.  This is the required code:

```
library(VGAM);

#Function to compute log-rho
#Input W and beta
LOG_RHO <- function(W, beta) { (beta-1)*W - VGAM::log1mexp(beta*abs(W)); }

#Example with W close to zero (so F is close to one)
W    <- -10^(-8);
beta <- 100;

LOG_RHO(W, beta);
[1] 13.81551

exp(LOG_RHO(W, beta));
[1] 999999.5
```

You can see that this allows you to calculate your function even for values of $F(x|\theta)$ that are extremely close to one.  This should serve your purposes well.  If you would like to know more about computational issues relating to log-probabilties, see related questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379335/) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383523/).