# Marginalising and taking the log of the likelihood

Tags: likelihood, marginal-distribution

Say you have a likelihood function $L(X|\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and you marginalise out $\theta_1$ and then take the log of the marginalised likelihood function. Would this be the same as taking the log and then marginalising?

Comment: I think what you're asking is under which circumstances logarithm and integration are exchangeable. There's [a related question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/434145).